# How a country is categorized as developed or developing?

Tags: development

Can you share an official source or reference of definition of a developed and developing country? some IMF or World Bank definition with link would be preferred. I need to write the reference in my thesis. Thanks

Comment: Hi Asif! DId you already search yourself for those indicators? Did you see how indicators such as the HDI is calculated, for example? DId you search in this forum already? I believe that research work is part of your thesis, right?

Comment: Related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13634/what-separates-rich-developing-nations-from-poor-developed-nations

Answer (score 1):

The terms developed and developing are UNDP terms.

Read the paper at the link below - it goes through the UNDP, World bank and IMF classifications and it's an IMF working paper so i'd class that as referenceable. At the very least it will point you to better sources.

https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2011/wp1131.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A developed economy is typically characteristic of a developed country with a relatively high level of economic growth and security. Common criteria for evaluating a country's level of development are income per capita or per capita gross domestic product, the level of industrialization, the general standard of living and the amount of technological infrastructure. Noneconomic factors, such as the human development index, which quantifies a country's levels of education, literacy and health into a single figure, can also be used to evaluate an economy or the degree of development.

Developed Economy Criteria:
The most common metric used to determine if an economy is developed or developing is per capita GDP, although no strict level exists for an economy to be considered either developing or developed. Some economists consider $12,000 to $15,000 per capita GDP to be sufficient for developed status while others do not consider a country developed unless its per capita GDP is above $25,000 or $30,000. The United States' per capita GDP in 2016 was $57,500.

Source: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/developed-economy.asp#ixzz5HPf3DGJf